# Preprocess a dataset with different feature types using a single Pipeline

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to preprocess and prepare a dataset to train a model. The dataset has some numerical and categorical features. Let's assume this is the dataset (presented as a Pandas DataFrame):

`Age,Gender,Height
23,M,170
33,M,195
31,F,165`

and we want to convert it to the following format, **using only the Transform functions in scikit-learn 0.19.0 and a single Pipeline object**:

`Age,Gender_M,Gender_F,Height
0.0,1,0,170
1.0,1,0,195
0.8,0,1,165`

The transforms are as follows:

Age: `MinMaxScaler`

Gender: `OneHotEncoder`

Height: Unchanged

Is this even possible (an alternative to make it slightly easier is to drop the Height feature for now)?

In my own attempts to come up with a solution, I noticed there is no way to apply a Transform function to a subset of all features, which made me believe this cannot be done using a single Pipeline. But I will be happy to be proven wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Have you had a go? If so, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50709774/edit) with your latest attempt. Hint: there are some good examples in the official docs (as well as across SO): [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) & [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The problem is a bit tricky. It is more than just knowing that certain Transform functions exist. It is about how to use them and apply them to the dataset partially and within a Pipeline object (which I am now doubtful is doable).

Comment: Other than the answer given by @AbhishekMishra, you can also look at [this scikit example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html) which explains this very use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own transformer to do the desired operations as following.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

class CustomTransformer((BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
   def __init__(self):
      self.one_hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder()
      self.min_max_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
   def fit(self, X, y):
       self.one_hot_encoder.fit(X.Gender)
       self.min_max_scaler.fit(X.Age)
       return self
   def transform(self, X, y):
       X["Gender"] = self.one_hot_encoder.transform(X["Gender"])
       X["Age"] = self.min_max_scaler(X["Age"]
       return X
```

Now you can use the Pipeline object on this transformer as follwoing:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline 
pipeline = Pipeline(("transform", CustomTransformer()), ("estimator", est))
pipeline.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. However, I need to purely rely on the existing Transform functions in scikit-learn without implementing a custom one.